# liquibase error - ERROR: relation "databasechangelog" does not exist. how can i fix this?

Tags: xml, postgresql, liquibase

I am looking for some advice as to what to do. Please bare with me as I am inexperienced with Liquibase.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


   <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
   <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <build>
       <pluginManagement>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                   <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.8.0</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                   </configuration>
                   <dependencies>
                     <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>42.1.1</version>
                     </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </pluginManagement>
   </build>
 </project>
```

changelog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="paul">
    
<sqlFile path="/Users/paulwakefield/DEV/Paul_1_March_2021_Branch/OPC/database/OPC_DB_CREATION_AND_UPDATES/remediation.sql"/>

    </changeSet>
 </databaseChangeLog>
```

remediation.sql - the first script i need to run.

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM app_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES REVOKE ALL ON SEQUENCES FROM app_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTIONS FROM app_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES REVOKE ALL ON TYPES FROM app_user;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM opsup_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES REVOKE ALL ON SEQUENCES FROM opsup_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTIONS FROM opsup_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES REVOKE ALL ON TYPES FROM opsup_user;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES REVOKE SELECT ON TABLES FROM support_user;

ALTER EVENT TRIGGER chown_objects DISABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER grant_object_privs DISABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER foreign_table_select_privs DISABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER view_privs DISABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER view_select_privs DISABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER table_select_privs DISABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER grant_usage DISABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER set_search_path DISABLE;

DROP FUNCTION chown_objects() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION grant_object_privs() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION foreign_table_select_privs() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION view_privs() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION view_select_privs() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION table_select_privs() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION grant_usage() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION set_search_path() CASCADE;

SET search_path TO opc_01;

CREATE FUNCTION chown_objects()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE obj RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() LOOP
            IF obj.object_type IN ('domain', 'function', 'schema', 'sequence', 'table', 'trigger', 'type', 'view')
            THEN
        EXECUTE 'ALTER ' || obj.object_type || ' ' || obj.object_identity || ' OWNER TO "build_user"';
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER chown_objects
    ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE DOMAIN', 'CREATE FOREIGN TABLE', 'CREATE FUNCTION', 'CREATE SCHEMA', 'CREATE SEQUENCE', 'CREATE TABLE', 'CREATE TABLE AS', 'CREATE TRIGGER', 'CREATE TYPE', 'CREATE VIEW')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE chown_objects();

ALTER EVENT TRIGGER chown_objects DISABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION grant_object_privs()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE obj RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() LOOP
            IF obj.object_type IN ('domain', 'function', 'sequence', 'table', 'type')
            THEN
        EXECUTE 'GRANT ALL ON ' || obj.object_type || ' ' || obj.object_identity || ' TO "app_user"';
        EXECUTE 'GRANT ALL ON ' || obj.object_type || ' ' || obj.object_identity || ' TO "opsup_user"';
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER grant_object_privs
    ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE DOMAIN', 'CREATE FUNCTION', 'CREATE SEQUENCE', 'CREATE TABLE', 'CREATE TABLE AS', 'CREATE TYPE')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE grant_object_privs();

ALTER EVENT TRIGGER grant_object_privs DISABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION foreign_table_select_privs()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE obj RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() LOOP
            IF obj.object_type IN ('table')
            THEN
        EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || obj.object_type || ' ' || obj.object_identity || ' TO "app_user"';
                EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || obj.object_type || ' ' || obj.object_identity || ' TO "opsup_user"';
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER foreign_table_select_privs
    ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE FOREIGN TABLE')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE foreign_table_select_privs();

ALTER EVENT TRIGGER foreign_table_select_privs DISABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION view_privs()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE obj RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() LOOP
            IF obj.object_type IN ('view')
            THEN
        EXECUTE 'GRANT ALL ON ' || obj.object_identity || ' TO "app_user"';
                EXECUTE 'GRANT ALL ON ' || obj.object_identity || ' TO "opsup_user"';
            END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER view_privs
    ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE VIEW')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE view_privs();

ALTER EVENT TRIGGER view_privs DISABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION view_select_privs()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE obj RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() LOOP
            IF obj.object_type IN ('view')
            THEN
        EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || obj.object_identity || ' TO "support_user"';
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER view_select_privs
    ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE VIEW')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE view_select_privs();

ALTER EVENT TRIGGER view_select_privs DISABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION table_select_privs()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE obj RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() LOOP
            IF obj.object_type IN ('table')
            THEN
        EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || obj.object_type || ' ' || obj.object_identity || ' TO "support_user"';
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER table_select_privs
    ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE TABLE', 'CREATE TABLE AS')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE table_select_privs();

ALTER EVENT TRIGGER table_select_privs DISABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION grant_usage()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE obj RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() LOOP
         IF obj.object_type IN ('schema')
         THEN
                EXECUTE 'GRANT USAGE ON ' || obj.object_type || ' ' || obj.object_identity || ' TO "app_user"';
                EXECUTE 'GRANT USAGE ON ' || obj.object_type || ' ' || obj.object_identity || ' TO "opsup_user"';
                EXECUTE 'GRANT USAGE ON ' || obj.object_type || ' ' || obj.object_identity || ' TO "support_user"';
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER grant_usage
    ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE SCHEMA')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE grant_usage();

ALTER EVENT TRIGGER grant_usage DISABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION set_search_path()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    all_current_schemas text := (SELECT string_agg(SCHEMA_NAME, ',' ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME ASC) FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT LIKE 'pg_%' AND SCHEMA_NAME NOT LIKE 'information_schema');
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'ALTER DATABASE ' || '{{ service }}_pgdb' || ' SET SEARCH_PATH TO ' || all_current_schemas;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER set_search_path
    ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE SCHEMA', 'ALTER SCHEMA', 'DROP SCHEMA', 'IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_search_path();

ALTER EVENT TRIGGER set_search_path DISABLE;

ALTER FUNCTION chown_objects() OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER FUNCTION grant_object_privs() OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER FUNCTION foreign_table_select_privs() OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER FUNCTION view_privs() OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER FUNCTION view_select_privs() OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER FUNCTION table_select_privs() OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER FUNCTION grant_usage() OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER FUNCTION set_search_path() OWNER TO postgres;

ALTER EVENT TRIGGER chown_objects ENABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER grant_object_privs ENABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER foreign_table_select_privs ENABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER view_privs ENABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER view_select_privs ENABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER table_select_privs ENABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER grant_usage ENABLE;
ALTER EVENT TRIGGER set_search_path ENABLE;
```

the first error i am receiving is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.8.0:update (default-cli) on project liquibase-maven-plugin: Error setting up or running Liquibase: Migration failed for change set /Users/paulwakefield/DEV/MavenPostgreSQL/OPC-upgrade-sql.xml::1::paul:
[ERROR]      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 74 in SQL CREATE FUNCTION chown_objects()
[ERROR] RETURNS event_trigger
[ERROR] LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
[ERROR] DECLARE obj RECORD. Expected terminating $$ [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE FUNCTION chown_objects()
[ERROR] RETURNS event_trigger
[ERROR] LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
[ERROR] DECLARE obj RECORD]
```

i then included splitStatements="false" in the < sqlFile > section. i am now receiving the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.8.0:update (default-cli) on project liquibase-maven-plugin: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.8.0:update failed: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL SELECT MAX(ORDEREXECUTED) FROM databasechangelog: ERROR: relation "databasechangelog" does not exist
[ERROR]   Position: 32
```

i am unsure how to combat these error or move forward with this. the databasechangelog has been created and is empty. the databasechangeloglock has been created. the first row show as locked = false.

if i use terminal to run these scripts i do not have any issue. i was hoping to create a version control in liquibase.

any advice would be most welcome!
thanks

Comment: To clarify you have no issues when running by terminal, are you running maven on the same system?  Do you also run the remidation.sql before you run liquibase on the termainal?  I am guessing this is a permissions issue, and probably due to the sql script.

Comment: that is correct, there is no issue while running in terminal. yes, maven is running on the same system. I have deleted and re-created the database quite a few times to have a fresh, basic database. once the remediation script is run through the posegres commands in terminal, i am able to run other scripts i need in both maven and teminal. hope this makes sense